# NotificationListenerService not including EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST

Tags: android

Trying to read `Notification.EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST` from a `MessagingStyle` notification received on a `NotificationListenerService`, like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = sbn.getNotification().extras.getParcelableArrayList(Notification.EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST);
```

Getting always null.

Printing `sbn.getNotification().extras.keySet()` I can see that `EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST = "android.people.list"` key is really not there, but according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST) it should.

I've tried on a Xiaomi device and on a Pixel2 emulator, both running Android 9 (API 28).

Something wrong with my code?

Comment: Does [`extractMessaginStyleFromNotification()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle#extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(android.app.Notification)) give you a non-null object back? Note that the [`addPerson()` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#addPerson(java.lang.String)) is totally separate from `MessagingStyle` - there's no requirement that an app developer use both.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ianhanniballake. It returns a non-null object. I got the `Person`s list from the `Message`s list at `getMessages()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`addPerson()` API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#addPerson(java.lang.String)) is completely independent from `MessagingStyle`, so you might be looking at apps that implement `MessagingStyle` but don't actually add any people, which would explain why `EXTRA_PEOPLE_LIST` is null.

If you're specifically looking for the people mentioned in the `MessagingStyle` part of the notification, you'll want to use [NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.extractMessagingStyleFromNotification()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle#extractMessagingStyleFromNotification(android.app.Notification)) to get the `MessagingStyle` object out of the `Notification`. After which you can call `getMessages()` and get the people from there.